Tensed infinitives across languages
As the Latin language shows, infinitives can be marked for tense (amare - present, amavisse - perfect).
English also shows that: to love, to have loved.
Can anyone suggest any literature regarding the question of tensed infinitives across languages and how they can be formed?
It would also be great if you could provide examples of languages that have tensed infinitives.

The Latin infinitive is more accurately marked for aspect, rather than tense; the same is true of the Classical Greek infinitive. Off the top of my head, I’d venture that most languages that have both tenses/aspects and infinitives also have the ability to combine the two. At least that’s the case for all the ones I can think of.

@JanusBahsJacquet Though to be fair, Ancient Greek has an infinitive that's marked for aspect or for future tense as an odd exception.

Also, the English example is specifically aspect rather than tense: you can combine the infinitive with all the auxiliaries you want (to have been being exploited) but not with tense (*to did, *to was).

The English perfect is not a tense, it's relative time. It means that, relative to the tense, the event happened before. So it makes sense that it can be used in a tenseless phrase.

also worth noting that English arguably doesn't have tensed infinitives because constructions like "to have loved", "to be going to love" etc are analytic constructions, whereas tense is generally required to be inflectional (additionally as @curiousdannii points out, even if we do want to consider them in the same terms as we would verbal inflection, these would be better understood as having retrospective and prospective aspect than past and future tense)

@JanusBahsJacquet, thank you (and all the others) for clarification! I have in mind Russian infinitives that can occur in main clauses: Человека не было видать (man-sg-acc not be-past-sg-3p_neuter to-see). It is kind of hard to find examples where the negation is placed right before the verb to be. There is more entries with it before the verb form with the suffix -ть: На эти деньги было не прожить (*На эти деньги не было прожить). So there is a question of whether there is a past infinitive in the examples given.

Russian infinitives lack tense, at least that is the standard view among Russian linguists - see e.g. Paducheva 2018 http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2

With видать it could be either Его не было видать or Его было не видать - this alteration occurs with the verbs of perception (видать, слыхать etc.)

@AlexB., Yeah, I read certain bits of the article. As far as I remember, the status of the verb быть was not specified. I checked the predicative with modality нужно: the negation can be placed before the verb: Ему не будет нужно брать на себя (extracted from the RNC).

@AlexB., as regards your last comment, it is interesting to note that I also found the alternation with just perception verbs (based on the RNC). As for the other verbs, sentences with them are judged as bad (I consulted a couple of people). Also, the only class of verbs able to be used as an infinitive in a main declarative clause consists of плевать, чихать and one curse verb (you can figure it out if you are a Russian native speaker). With these verbs the negation can be placed before быть: Мне не было плевать на него.

@AlexB., also, what do you think the syntax is for the usage we are discussing? Does it have the structure similar to sentences like Мне было холодно so that the VP with an infinitive as its head forms a predicative?

In a nutshell, your examples are a subtype of the so called независимый инфинитив (independent infinitive) and that is why it attracts the negative marker, unlike the dependent infinitive. A good place to start is Paducheva 2017  http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC Incidentally, she also studied negation.

You may also find Fleisher 2006 of some interest, esp. pp. 7-8 and example 12, https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.uwm.edu/dist/8/199/files/2016/06/Fleisher_RussianDatSubj-2k6ibfp.pdf and Moore, John, and David M. Perlmutter. “Case, Agreement, and Temporal Particles in Russian Infinitival Clauses.” Journal of Slavic Linguistics 7, no. 2 (1999): 219–46. http://www.jstor.org/stable/24599646

In Aymara, tense can be “added” to infinitives, e.g. saraña “to go” vs sarañäni “to go in the future”. The nominal form is verbalised and then a verbal suffix is added so morphologically the new form isn’t nominal but can be used as an infinitive.
